# How to keep relative paths in CSS for images and fonts in Laravel Mix

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

When Laravel Webpack/Mix executes and converts SASS to CSS, it changes the relative paths like `url('../images/background.png');` to absolute paths like `url('/images/background.png');`.

Is it possible that the paths are not updated and kept as relative?

The reason is that the deployment could be in different folders on different servers so that the relative paths will work on all folder structures. E.g., it will work on `http://www.example.com/` as well as `http://www.example.com/subfolder/`. But if an absolute path is used, then in the case of the subfolder, the CSS will not find the images and fonts.

Is there some other best practice to handle this situation?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#working-with-stylesheets):

> By default, Laravel Mix and Webpack will find `example.png`, copy it to your `public/images` folder, and then rewrite the `url()` within your generated stylesheet. As such, your compiled CSS will be.
>
> As useful as this feature may be, it's possible that your existing folder structure is already configured in a way you like. If this is the case, you may disable `url()` rewriting like so:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/app/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({
       processCssUrls: false
   });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#working-with-stylesheets

Comment: this works! but another problem it creates is that it does not process vendor urls. for e.g. font-awesome fonts urls are now attempted from `public/fonts` folder instead of `public/fonts/vendor/font-awsome...`, is there some way to bypass this?

Comment: for now, I just copied the font-awesome fonts in my assets/fonts directory (as I am already using mix.copy() to copy images and fonts from assets to public directory), so it works with `processCssUrls: false`, but there has to be some solid solution that works for vendor css as well as app css

Comment: It's possible to set `processCssUrls` only on certain files which should solve the problem See https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/url-rewriting#per-file-rewrite-settings

Comment: I have disabled processCssUrls and also individual processUrls for every scss files however i am still getting very strange behavior. 
If i remove scss files entirely from my mix chain then it is working almost 100 times faster  so i guess there is something with compiling scss.  Dunno but may be path issues..